# preg_replace and twitter

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have this code to make clickable links into my app:

```
$string = preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow">$1</a>', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', '<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$1" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', $string);
```

Above code is working fine, but suddenly Im seeing some links like `http://twitter.com/#!/username` and `http://domain.com/hello@all/` and breaks everything, any idea how to fix my code?

string var comes directly from twitter API, here is an example:     `$string = 'http://twitter.com/!#/metallica  http://someurl.com/get@stuff/';`

Thanks in advance.
Edited: added string value.

Comment: Try `!(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=!*]+)!i` as your regular expression instead.

Comment: can you put up value of `$string`??

Comment: @erisco thanks, but im getting this error: Unknown modifier '*' /@experimentX what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe `!(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=!\*]+)!i`

Comment: Okay, maybe `!(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=\!*]+)!i`

Comment: @erisco nice dude! first link type (#!) is working, @ link type still breaking...

Answer (score 2):

Why are you tampering with those URL? If they are direct links, then just leave them as they are! Simple regex pattern like this:

```
((?:f|ht)tp://[^\s]*)
```

will match any URL inside the string.

So, your code should be just:

```
$string = preg_replace('/((?:f|ht)tp:\/\/[^\s]*)/i', '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow">$1</a>', $string);
```